# How can I remove blood stains with console command

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I've fixed up and remodeled castle Volkihar to a more royal vampiric look.
However, all of the bloodstains takes away from the more civilized and decent look for my vampires.
How can I remove all of the bloodstains from the wall and floor?
Can it be done with console command?

Answer (score 2):

If you are willing to try a mod, you could use the Castle Volkihar Rebuilt mod (for both the [Legendary Edition](https://www.nexusmods.com/skyrim/mods/65502) and [Special Edition](https://www.nexusmods.com/skyrimspecialedition/mods/324)).

Else for strictly console commands, select the blood texture in question in the console. Follow it up by the `MarkForDelete` command. Also backup your save before using console commands.

Comment: I have done those mods but would rather be free of them due to the amount of memory on my game and the risk of something going wrong with the mod that was created by the modder.
I would really like to do things myself as to not have to rely on someone else work.
You feel me?
So how can you select the blood texture and 'markfordelete' without deleting the entire floor or wall that it seems to be attached to?